# How to build a hashcode to support symmetry

Tags: java, math, vector

I wrote a PointPair class which has a 4 doubles representing the coordinate values of 2 points where first point, A= (a1,a2), second point, B=(b1,b2). I implemented hashCode and equals methods in my class and all worked well until I was told that it needs to support symmetry, i.e. a PointPair object built with A,B needs to be equal to PointPair built with B,A.

```
class PointPair {
    public final double a1, a2, b1, b2;

    public PointPair(Point a, Point b) {
        this.a1 = a.x; this.a2 = a.y;
        this.b1 = b.x; this.b2 = b.y;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(a1, a2, b1, b2); // fix me!
    }

    private boolean bothEqual(double d1, d2) {
       return Double.compare(d1,d2) == 0 ;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if ((obj == null) || !(obj instanceof PointPair))
            return false;
        PointPair pObj = (PointPair) obj;

        //test for same reference or value match
        return (obj == this) || (bothEqual(a1, pObj.a1) && bothEqual(a2, pObj.a2) && bothEqual(b1, pObj.b1) && bothEqual(b2, pObj.b2)) ||
                (bothEqual(a1, pObj.b1) && bothEqual(a2, pObj.b2) && bothEqual(b1, pObj.a1) && bothEqual(b2, pObj.a2)) ; // symmetry match
    }

}
```

I changed my equals method to support that (pls see above) but I'm looking for ideas to fix the hashCode method or some other scheme for the class.
One idea that came to my mind was to compute a dot-product metric using two imaginary vectors that represented the points (thinking geometrically) and the angle between them.  Will this always give a unique value for the 2 points in my point-pair?

```
    public int hashCode() {
         double dotprod = (a1*b1)+(a2*b2) ;
         double mag1 = Math.sqrt(a1*a1+a2*a2)
         double mag2 = Math.sqrt(b1*b1+b2*b2)
         double angle = Math.acos(dotprod/(mag1*mag2))
         Objects.hash(dotprod, angle)
    }
```

Comment: `return Double.hashCode(a1*b1+a2*b2)` ?

Comment: Why don't you use composition instead of storing `Double` coordinates in your `PointPair class`?

Comment: You could also always store the points in the same order, in the constructor, and then don't worry about it in equals and hashCode.

Comment: If you can, sort your points when you create the instance (e.g., a is lower/lefter than b), or just sort them before hash-coding and equals.

Comment: assylias: that value would not be unique to the quartet which would cause unwanted clashes @Yuri: I intended to use double because I saw no need to take the overhead of composed Point objects. @ Rob @ JBNizet: I would need to sort (keeping the pair intact) in the X or Y coordinate only. That would work, but I was thinking about a possible future need where I may want to use the class to retrieve the order in which the points were supplied. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @Don there will be clashes one way or another...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with addition. In the same style as your existing `hashCode`, it would be:

```
Objects.hash(a1, a2) + Objects.hash(b1, b2)
```

This is, for example, how [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#hashCode--) specifies its `hashCode` to be order-independent.

Another way would be to use XOR.

Comment: I've been reading about `HashCode`, Just out of curiosity, I know the sum idea is from `Set`, but why can't we implement *multiplication* or *division* or even *subtraction*. I mean if `hash` returns an `integer` resulted from some `algorithm` and the whole idea behind `HashCode` is to accelerate the search from the `Map/Set` via providing addresses/bucketing. How do we know that *sum* here is better than *subtraction* and so on?

Comment: You could use multiplication in this case but division and subtraction won't work. The operator must be symmetric, i.e. it must be the case that `a op b == b op a` which is not always true for division and subtraction. A lot of how you choose to implement hashing depends on what your data looks like. `a*b` would yield fewer collisions if `a` and `b` are typically small. If `a` and `b` are typically large then `a*b` could overflow.

Comment: Thanks much for the response which makes me realize that I could also have refactored my class to keep Set<Point>  pts instead of the original four Doubles, and then delegated the hashCode function to pts.hashCode. BTW, could you also illustrate the XOR way?

Comment: XOR is just the same as the addition example but you use `^` instead of `+`.